# nginx reverse proxy rewriting locations

Tags: nginx, proxypass

ok, so i have a virtual machine http://10.0.8.247:80/phppgadmin/ running phppgadmin. I wanted to expose phppgadmin to the internet on admin.example.com, so I did

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name admin.example.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass              http://10.0.8.247:80/;
  }
}
```

and this works as expected. going to admin.example.com/phppgadmin proxies the request to 10.0.8.247 and i get the response I want. Now,
i wanted to change things a little: have the same response on admin.example.com/postgres. So I tried

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name admin.example.com;
  location /postgres/ {
    proxy_pass              http://10.0.8.247:80/phppgadmin/;
  }
}
```

but this keeps failing me. The browser indicates that its trying to connect to 10.0.8.247 which naturally wont work, since I dont expose the virtual machines directly to the internet. Anyone got a hint? Thanks in advance, P.

======================================

Solution floows (Thanks lots, cnst!)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name admin.example.com;

  location /postgres/ {
    proxy_pass              http://10.0.8.247:80/phppgadmin/;
    proxy_redirect          default;
  }
}
```

works like charm. Also note that

```
proxy_redirect              default;
```

is the same ase

```
proxy_redirect             http://10.0.8.247:80/phppgadmin/ /postgres/;
```

Comment: Please post your web server access and error logs. I think I know the problem but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: @Killua, glad it works, thanks for accept, +1.  You now have a rep of 18, which is above 15, and gives you the upvote privilege, feel free to try it on my accepted answer. ;)  BTW, you never mentioned what was your actual issue -- the `default` is already default, so, what was it that you had issue with?

Comment: @cnst I wondered too why it makes a difference because `default` is the default (says the docs), but adding it fixed it for me too - strange, but great.  My case is proxying to Apache on localhost:8080 and Apache was returning redirects with Location of that, ignoring anything I try to set on Host.  Nginx to the rescue (as usual!), setting `proxy_redirect default` handles it and returns the correct Location outward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is controlled through the [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) directive.

If your config is exactly as described, then it means that nginx isn't automatically normalising `:80` part of the `proxy_pass` for the `proxy_redirect` to work correctly (which wouldn't surprise me too much, because most people don't proxy_pass to port 80 anyways), in which case, you can try either removing `:80`, or adding an explicit `proxy_redirect` directive.

Otherwise, if you're using regular expressions or variables in your `location` or `proxy_pass` directives, then don't, or just add an explicit `proxy_redirect`, too.